# Can I trigger a Google Assistant action without a conversation?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to develop an action for my Google Assistant. I'd like for it to be fire and forget type deal (i.e. 'Add x to my todo list').
The problem is, the assistant won't recognise the command without me first starting a conversation with the assistant app that the action exists within.
(Hey Google, I want to talk to ... )

I'm using webhooks to call a webserver that will handle the request.

I can't use IFTTT in this instance as it needs to be available for everyone in my home. (IFTTT actions are private or public to EVERYONE)

Is there any way to trigger an action without having to say anything else (besides 'Hey Google')?

Answer (score 5):

There's a few ways to complete a quick action. There is [implicit triggering](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit), when your action gets matched based on a certain set of requests.

> You: Hey Google, add paying taxes to my to-do list
>
> Google: Ok, for that you may want to try talking to My App.
>
> You: Okay
>
> My App: Ok, added paying taxes

That may work, although still may require an extra step with the Google Assistant. Alternatively, you can also [launch a specific intent](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit) in a conversation without a full conversation.

> You: Hey Google, tell My App to add paying taxes to my to-do list
>
> Google: Ok, getting My App
>
> My App: Ok, added paying taxes

A third alternative would be to use the Google Assistant [shortcuts](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7390802?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) feature which will take something you say and interpret that as something else. It only works for static utterances, so it may not work in your case.

> You: Hey Google, add paying taxes to my to-do list
>
> Google: Ok, getting My App
>
> My App: Ok, added paying taxes

In this scenario, you'd need to have the shortcut "add paying taxes to my to-do list" to be interpreted as "tell My App to add paying taxes to my to-do list".

If this is designed to be used by several people in your home, you may need to think about how and whether each account should be able to access the same lists.

Comment: Regarding this answer, is there a way to skip the "Ok, getting My App" line and just get the response from the app?  Combined with Routines to mask the command so that I don't have to say "tell My App to...." prior to the command, is it possible to make an action appear natively within the Assistant the way IFTTT does?

Comment: No, there is no way to have it seem "native" for a general conversational action.

Comment: With the new Actions Builder invocations are covered in [Build invocation models](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/build/invocation).